# Error when docker-compose "/usr/local/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.8.so.1.0: "

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, docker, docker-compose

Hi i tried run my project with docker, the problem ocurred when i build the image, i use the commando 
 "whereis python" and  recive the path of directory but i build the image and the error is the next:

```
/usr/local/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.8.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I use manjaro, the problem is the folder /usr/local/bin/python dont exist, I try modified the file

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

and add the path of python which is

```
include /usr/lib/python3.8/
```

the Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9.0b1-alpine3.11
WORKDIR /cloud
ENV FLASK_APP Server.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["flask","run"]
```

the docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  cloud-flask-back:
    build: ./Flask
    ports:
        - "5000:5000"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

I hope you can help me

Comment: Install binaries only through a package manager that can automatically install dependencies as well. Don't ever just copy them in -- even when it works in the short term, it eventually ends in sorrow. There are source-based package managers like Nix and Portage that can compile exactly the software you need, if that's the route you want to go.

Comment: If you show us your Dockerfile and/or docker-compose.yml, we might be able to suggest a concrete fix.

Comment: Okey 
I just edited my question thanks

Comment: You're using Python 3.9 image but the other things you're talking about is Python 3.8. Your app is supposed to run on what version? Also I think the case that you're using a beta version of base image can be cause of your problem. Can you switch to a stable tag and check the result?

Comment: Yes, i check woth version 3.8 but its the same error

Comment: When this error shows up? When building or when you want to run it?

Comment: When i building, but when i use pip install requirements.txt its works

Comment: Are you building any C extensions outside the image, and then copying them in? If so, you want to make sure you build the extensions _inside_ the image.

Comment: No, i dont use extensions outside the image

Comment: @Derick, what OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

i resolved it, i use actually manjaro linux and i install docker with snap package, for a estrange error,
when I use docker-compose of my project it shows me the error in the title. I resolve it uninstall docker snap